# ¿Cómo asignar carpetas a un usuario especifico en Linux y cuando inicie sesión le aparezcan solo las carpetas que se le asignaron?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, samba

Estoy configurando un servidor samba, pero en una parte me piden que se cree varios usuarios y a dichos usuarios se le asignen carpetas especificas para que cuando dicho usuario sea usado e inicie sesión solo le aparezcan las carpetas que se le asignaron, ¿Cómo seria la configuración para poder realizar eso?.

Answer (score 0):

Hasta donde yo sé no hay una "gpo" al estilo active directory que lo haga automaticamente.

Yo en mi caso modifico un fichero .desktop (acceso directo) de nautilus ( o explorador que se esté usando ) y le añado la ruta junto al protocolo de conexion.

osea ser, si ejecutas en terminal "nautilus smb://USER@SERVER/PATH" o sin añadir usuario... "nautilus smb://SERVER/PATH" abriría un nautilus directamente a esa ruta... si usas eso como un acceso directo, se abrirá siempre la carpeta al clickar desde el escritorio en el acceso directo.

Comment: Tambien, volviendo a leer lo que quieres... Se puede interpretar que lo que quieres es que el home de cada usuario sea una carpeta de smb, lo cual tambien es posible de hacer.